# Why isnt my fetch function firing when using useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I want to reduce my general dependency on useEffects and have created a hook file that fetches from an api

I have the following code setup:

```
    const searchCharactersAPI = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const res = await fetch(
                `https://narutodb.xyz/api/character${
                    search !== "" ? `/search?name=${search}` : ""
                }`,
            );
            const resJSON = await res?.json();

            setCharactersData(resJSON);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("There was an error", error);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, [search]);

  const handleSearch = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }


 <input className="flex w-full border-0 outline-none focus-visible:false rounded-lg p-2 text-black" placeholder="Search characters..." type="text" onChange={handleSearch} value={search} />
```

if i was to change the searchCharactersAPI useCallback fn to a useEffect it will work as expected but i am wondering why it doesnt fire when it is a useCallback when exact same dependencies

Comment: Where do you _call_ it?

Comment: @tkausl I call it initally in an useEffect thats within the hook file and then i was hoping it would update as i type into the input.. please not that the input is in its own page component while the useCallback itself is in the hook

Comment: You'll need to manually call `searchCharactersAPI()` each time you want to re-search based on a new search term. All the `useCallback()` does is return the same reference to the function from previous renders if its dependencies are the same.

Answer (score 0):

`useCallback` doesn't call the function every time a dependency changes. It just returns a new function reference. Either you have to call the function in the `useCallback`, or you have to call the `searchCharactersAPI` in `handleSearch`.

On a side note, if you're trying to remove effects from your code, then using `useCallback` to execute side effects is not the way to go. Handle user events in an event handler like you are supposed to.